# React Js / Active item on menu with state

Tags: reactjs, styled-components

Hello I would like to know how I could create a state for when an item from my menu is active (when a user clicks)

code:

```
const MenuDashBoard = () => {
  const toggleMenu = useSelector(state => state.menuStatus.menuStatus);
  return (
      <GridMenu desktop={toggleMenu ? '240px' : '75px'} mobileGrid = {toggleMenu ? '31.25%' : '12.5%'} wdscreen = { toggleMenu? '80%' : '2%'}>
        <SidebarNav>
          <SidebarUl> 

            <SideBarLi >

              <SideBarA>
                <Icon name='home' size='large' style={{ marginRight: '10px', padding: 0, opacity:'1', height:' 1em'}} /> 
                <p style={{display: toggleMenu ? 'block' : 'none'}} >Home</p>
              </SideBarA>

            </SideBarLi>

            <SideBarLi >

              <SideBarA>
                <Icon name='home' size='large' style={{ marginRight: '10px', padding: 0, opacity:'1', height:' 1em'}} /> 
                <p style={{display: toggleMenu ? 'block' : 'none'}}>Home2</p>
              </SideBarA>

            </SideBarLi>

          </SidebarUl>
        </SidebarNav>
      </GridMenu>
  );
}
```

Basically I wanted to create something with state to save the active item in order to enable some css

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give name to each of them and write an onClick for those, as your code is incomplete, it's hard for me to do so. Here is the same type code you want:

Code :

```
state={
        username:'',//it tracks which element is being pressed
        user:['maifeeulasad','maifee']    
    }

    constructor(props){
        super(props);
        this.userList=this.userList.bind(this);
        this.setUsername=this.setUsername.bind(this);
    }

    setUsername = (e) =>{
        this.setState({username:e.target.getAttribute('name')})
    }

    userList = () =>{
        return this.state.user.map((u)=>{ 
            console.log(u);
            return <li onClick={this.setUsername} id={u} name={u}>{u}</li>; 
        }); 
    }

    render() {
    if(this.state.username==='' )
    {
        return (
            <div>
                Developer list:
                {this.userList()}
            </div>
        );

    }
    else
    {
        return (
            <div>
                Developer list:
                {this.userList()}
                <a href={"https://github.com/"+this.state.username}>View My GitHub Profile</a>
            </div>
            );
    }
}
```

[sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/embed/spring-sun-ll0q2?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark)

In this code :

```
setUsername = e => {
    this.setState({ username: e.target.getAttribute("name") });
  };
```

To achieve that, let's define a css first 'colo'

Now in our code just add `className={this.state.username === u ? "colo" : ""}` in `return <li onClick={this.setUsername} id={u} name={u}>{u}</li>;`, it will do your job. Check out the updated sandbox, it should work.

If works, don't forget to tick and accept as answer.

Comment: UI Asad Hello thanks but i think i expressed myself wrong
i need this with respect to the menu item
that is when clicking on a menu item it would be active changing color and could never have 2 active items just one

Comment: @MykonSpt checkout the updated answer and sandbox, it works as you asked

Comment: that's really it but I got a doubt
as i am using example menu item:

Home
AddProducts etc etc
I would need to somehow identify this name or maybe the url / addProducts
ie in url / addProducts the item add Products = a
Would you help me out of this?

Comment: render based on url, is different, ask a different question, yes I can help you with that too, i think... that can be done using router and `this.props.param.match. ...` @MykonSpt

Answer (score 0):

You can use hooks with useState and depending on the state set the styling , here is an example from a chat app, depending on what user is online it will change the css from green or black

```
function FriendListItem(props) {
  const [isOnline, setIsOnline] = useState(null);

  ...

  return (
    <li style={{ color: isOnline ? 'green' : 'black' }}>
      {props.friend.name}
    </li>
  );
}
```

Comment: and how could I get a click on my <Li>? I need active after click or on click on active